# HP Envy 14, Ubuntu 10.10 and trouble with the graphics cards

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card

A few days ago I bought a HP Envy 14, containing 2 graphics card: An integrated Intel graphics card, and an ATI HD 5650. I've installed Ubuntu 10.10 32-bit on the machine. Most things work fine out of the box, but the graphics cards are giving me trouble.

When booting, I get the message "failed to get i915 symbols, graphics turbo disabled". Then the screen blanks out during the remaining boot period. I am able to get the display working by changing to one of the consoles, then closing and opening the laptop's lid.

It seems that Ubuntu gets confused about which card to use.

I've read [here](http://www.andreas-demmer.de/en/2010/07/18/testbericht-linux-auf-dem-hp-envy-14) that I should be able to turn off one the cards by echoing keywords into `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`, but that path is not available on my system. The BIOS does not have any methods to switch of the ATI card.

Help anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the actual BIOS that we can download have this feature to disable one of the Display card.

I'm here starting this war to show my screen on my 22 monitor using HDMI output.

I'm unable to use the driver provided by ATI, the X server is not starting. I'm only capable of start X-server using Intel video.

UPDATE:
I found some solutions on this blog: http://linuxenvy.blogspot.com/
But assume that I`m very disappointed that I could not use my 22 monitor on my new notebook using ubuntu. Needer using HDMI or mini-display-port